# Style stored in command

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-styles

I have created a `\newcommand` with some arguments that allow me to call an other command.

Command syntax:

```
\newcommand{\nodeperso}[1]{\node[\noexpand\type#1](){\noexpand\nom#1};}
```

I have declared a style:

```
Boite/.style={rounded rectangle,font=\ttfamily}
```

After that I declare two other new commands like this:

```
\newcommand{\typeAAB}{Boite}
\newcommand{\nomAAB}{coucou}
```

I want to call the `\nodeperso` command with `AAB` as argument (`\nodeperso{AAB}`). `\nomAB` is correctly expanded but not `\typeAB`.

Maybe the use of `pgfkeys` can provide better results but I am not familiar with the syntax.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\nodeperso}[1]{\node[\noexpand\type#1](){\noexpand\nom#1};}
\newcommand{\typeAAB}{Boite}
\newcommand{\nomAAB}{coucou}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Boite/.style={rounded rectangle,font=\ttfamily}]

\node[Boite]{coucou};  %% OK
\node[\typeAAB]{\nomAAB};  %% OK

\nodeperso{AAB}  %% NOK

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it should rather be a `\csname type#1\endcsname` instead of `\noexpand\type#1`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\newcommand{\nodeperso}[1]{\node[\csname type#1\endcsname](){\csname nom#1\endcsname};}
\newcommand{\typeAAB}{Boite}
\newcommand{\nomAAB}{coucou}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Boite/.style={rounded rectangle,font=\ttfamily}]

\node[Boite]{coucou};  %% OK
\node[\typeAAB]{\nomAAB};  %% OK

\nodeperso{AAB}  %% NOK

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea of where I can find any complete information about `\csname`, `\endcsname`, `\expandafter` and `\noexpand` command?

Comment: Wait, shouldn't your code give "coucou" as well as the node text?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, I've forgotten to remove the second `\noexpand` -- will update

Comment: @Guuk: I am sure there are many questions on those elementary `TeX` commands, as well as in `TeX by Topic` for example. But I can add some short explanation

Comment: I already use it many times but I don't really understand the purpose of these commands. They seem to be not well explain or I don't find the right explanation. I don't want to take your time. I will look more precisely for an description. Thank you.

Comment: @Guuk: I will add it later on, ok?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer  No problem, take your time :-)

Comment: I recommend `[style/.expand twice=\csname type#1\endcsname]` for cases where `\type#1` contains more than one key. (However, I wouldn't replace the key-value system with macros to begin with.)